# How to bind a function with html component?

Tags: javascript, html, web, components

Here is my setup. I create a html page and put an input component on this page whose type is text. I set the readonly  property for the component because I want to display date and time in this component so user can not change it. My question is how can I diplay date and time in this component so that its value keep on changing as the time change. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `jquery` for that

html

`<label id="clock"></label>`

jquery

```
var updateClock = function() {
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
}

var now = new Date();
var s = pad(now.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
        pad(now.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
        pad(now.getUTCSeconds());

 $('#clock').html(s);

var delay = 1000 - (now % 1000);
setTimeout(updateClock, delay);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this if you are using the html component id

```
  $("#main").bind("click",function(){
      alert("The is id.");

//or you can call the function 
    });
```

Or
Just try this if you are using the html component class

```
 $(".main").bind("click",function(){
      alert("The is class.");
//or you can call the function 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On every datetime update run this code

```
 document.getElementById("input_id").value = "date content";
```

Comment: Please check the last part of your answer.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTag("input").value === reference error`